# parsing XML into DB using java in simplest form

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**Problem:** I have a XML which i want to parse it and create a table by the name of the XML file and load only certain values into the table.

i have found few libraries but i feel in built JAXB ( or is there is any other simple way ?) is enough to do this simple task.

I had no idea about parsing XML before this,  gone through so many tutorials all talks about creating a class & java object from XML, My requirement is very simple here just extract three values for set of elements(method="add") under the root element(class=" java.util.ArrayList) .

Can some one help how can i achieve this ?

The XML i am trying parse is here http://txtup.co/wSXCA

**I need to extract the below properties under each void method="add" in void class=" java.util.ArrayList" :**

```
@property(description)
@property(jndiName)
@property(url)
```

Comment: Hm, the file you linked describes serialized JavaBeans. Why don't you just decode them using [XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by home i was able to decode my XMl document. I was not aware it is a java serialized object xml before raising the question, Any ways i was able to get my XML decode as below.

```
 XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(
                      new BufferedInputStream(
                          new FileInputStream("Test.xml")));
   Object result = d.readObject();
   d.close();
```